# Ignore any non-lowercase characters (such as digits, uppercase, and symbols) and get the value of k

Tags: javascript

My programming task is as follows:

> You are given a string of letters on a first line of input. The first
>   two characters are the number of letters that your program should
>   examine (a number from 01 to 30) Your program should print out all the
>   different lowercase letters in the string as well as an offset count
>   as described below.
>
> Going left to right from the first occurrence of a character. If that
>   character is repeated after k more characters, k should be added to
>   the count. If a character is not repeated, the count is 0.    All
>   characters should be lowercase, and ignore any non-lowercase
>   characters (such as digits, uppercase, and symbols). Include error
>   checking for the number of characters and print ERROR if there is a
>   failure.
>
> ```
> Sample Input #1
> 06ababab
>
> Sample Output #1
> a 6
> b 6
>
> Sample Input #2
> 12hello there world
>
> Sample Output #2
> h 7
> e 16
> l 1
> o 0
> t 0
> r 0
>
> Sample Input #3
> 70hello there world
>
> Sample Output #3
> ERROR
> ```

I used JavaScript to code the solution as follows:

```
function lettersCount(str) {

    // Convert to lowerCase
    str.toLowerCase();

    // Create an empty object to hold the combo of the letter and count
    var output = {};

    // Get the number of letters we examine
    var num = +str.slice(0, 2);

    // Check error
    if (num < 01 || num > 30) {
        console.log("ERROR");

        return;
    }

    // Get the character string
    var char = str.slice(2);
    var charLen = char.length;

    if (num <= charLen) {

        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            var letter1 = char[i];

            output[letter1] === undefined ? output[letter1] = 0 : output[letter1] += k; // k = char.indexOf(repeatedletter) - char.indexOf(firstoccurrenceofthesameletter)
        }

    } else if (num > charLen) {

        for (var j = 0; j < charLen; j++) {
            var letter2 = char[j];

            output[letter2] === undefined ? output[letter2] = 0 : output[letter2] += k; // k = char.indexOf(repeatedletter) - char.indexOf(firstoccurrenceofthesameletter)
        }
    }

    // log out the combo of the letter and count to the console
    for (var property in output) {
        console.log(property, output[property]);
    }
}

lettersCount("12hello there world");

// lettersCount("12hello there world");
// lettersCount("70hello there world");
```

My two questions:

1. How do I ignore any non-lowercase characters (such as digits, uppercase, and symbols) and still get right the number of letters that my program should examine?
2. How can I get the value of k if that character is repeated after k more characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function determines if a character is a lowercase letter

```
function isLowerCase(ch) {
  var n = ch.charCodeAt(0)
  // 'a' = 97
  // 'b' = 98
  // ...
  // 'z' = 122
  return n >= 97 && n <= 122
}
```

For the value of `k` I'd keep an object which maps a character to an array of occurrence indices, for example the string `"ababab"` would be saved as `"{"a":[0,2,4],"b":[1,3,5]}"`, finally for each lower case you just have to iterate this array and add `indices[i] - indices[0]` where `i > 0` to the `count` value

This is a programming assignment you should do but anyways I'm dropping my solution just in case you need, it'd be awesome if you compare it to your own solution **after you finished the assignment please**

[solution](http://jsbin.com/peperi/edit?js,console)

Comment: I didn't think this way. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Answers:

**1** How do I ignore any non-lowercase characters (such as digits, uppercase, and symbols) and still get right the number of letters that my program should examine?

You can easily ignore digits, uppercase characters and symbols by using an `if` statement like such:

```
if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') {

  // do your processing here

} else {

    // ignored!

}
```

**2** How can I get the value of *k* if that character is repeated after *k* more characters?

You would, first, need to remember at which index (string position) you encountered the character first. An `associative array` (also known as an `object` in javascript) is a good way to do this:

```
{
   "a": {
       "count": 0,
       "firstPos": 0
   },
   "b": {
      "count":0,
      "firstPos": 1
   }
}
```

It has the following advantages (over an array structure):

1. You can easily check if a `key` already exists. In the above example, `"a"`, `"b"` are the keys.

```
if(myObject[myKey]) { // if myObject has a key called myKey

    // do something

}
```

2. You can easily retrieve the `value` of a property if you know the `key` (without using a loop to search for it).
3. Similarly, you can easily modify the `value` of the property without using a loop.

**Note:** As far as I can tell, only the first occurrence is needed for doing the counting no matter how many repetitions exist.

Comment: Good reasoning. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If my answer helped you then please upvote it or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why not use a regex function to check if it is a letter? If it is all English letters then you could use something like this to check for all lower case letters. chaCodeAt returns ASCII code of the letter, lowercase letters are from 97 to 122.

   if(letter1.charCodeAt(0) < 97 || letter1.charCodeAt(0) > 122)
   continue;

Or you could separately check for numbers and letters using something like this.

```
if(!isNaN(letter1)) //checking if it is a number
 continue;
if(letter1 != letter1.toLowerCase()) //checking for lower case
 continue;
```

I would choose the first one over the last.

2. Since the string to be evaluated would be relatively small, why not iterate over it to get indices, and keep a count as below.

   if(letter1 in output) //if output already has calculation for the particular letter no need to do calculation again
    continue;
   var count = 0;
   for(var m=firstIndex=str.indexOf(letter1); m<=num;m++) {
    if (str[m] === letter1) 
     count = count + (m-firstIndex);
    }
   output[letter1] === undefined ? output[letter1] = count:'';

Comment: I did think about regex earlier, but didn't pop up a good one, but yours is a good one. Thank you for your help.